# Why would one use Scala over Java

Tags: java, scala

I am totally into Scala as a language ... and still I struggle with why any company should use  Scala over Java. Is Scala just syntatic sugar on top of the JVM or are there fundamental improvements in Scala over Java that would improve **real world** applications?

Comment: I asked [essentially the same question on Quora.com.](http://www.quora.com/Why-should-a-Java-developer-consider-switching-to-Scala?q=scala%20java) You may find the answers there helpful.

Comment: The topic of Java vs Scala has been covered already in more specific questions, I would suggest you search for those. You'll find questions relating to several "real world" things (such as web application development).

Comment: There are many questions that answer the Scala / Java question from a technical point of view. For example, Which is a better framework Java/GWT or Scala/Lift, Scala vs Java Performance and Memory ... but I haven't seen any answer for using Scala over Java that would so clearly benefit how I create real applications.

Comment: I thought the point of this site was to give answers from a technical point of view.